Recently added bug to amsmath
It seems that amsmath(?) has just got a bug. Below there is a MWE. For some reason it does not properly compile any longer. It used to work fine. (I am on the last version of MiKTeX on Windows, with all packages updated)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\{\dots\}$
\end{document}

During compilation it gets:
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\GenericWarning ...tchoice@ \else 4\fi \endcsname 
                                                  \protect \GenericWarning  
l.6 $\{\dots\}
              $
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

To make the source properly compile, it is needed to add {} after \dots.

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1448

Thanks @JosephWright for signalling this

it's better to use \relax than {} as {} can affect spacing  but that isn't the same issue as 1448 exactly (or at least it's a different test)

An update reverting to the June release of amsmath (apart from documentation improvements) has been sent to ctan and will be in texlive and miktex shortly

Thanks @DavidCarlisle to update us on this

This was a bug in the November 2024 release of amsmath. The code was reverted after a few days and the version of amsmath on CTAN and in texlive has been reverted to a version without this problem.

Original answer
A temporary fix that disables part of the last update is
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\gdef\testif@#1#2#3#4\testif@{\@tempswafalse}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
$\{\dots\}$
\end{document}

We hope to push out an amsmath update (with a different change) in the next day or so.

Caution: the version of amsmath.sty in texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/amsmath, dated 2024/1030, still has the bug, whereas the version in texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, dated 2024/11/05 has the bug fixed.

@murray amsmath-dev has gone to ctan today as well it will be identical to the main version, we just staggered the ctan upload to give them time to breath
