Why does this no longer compile?
This MWE shows code that formerly compiled just fine under pdflatex. It no longer does. What is the cause?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\formfamily}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\family}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{;}} m }{\dofamily#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dofamily}{mmm}{\formfamily{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2 \in #3}}}

\begin{document}

Let
\[
x = \family{x_{i}; i; I}.
\]
and
\[
y = \family{y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}, \dots}.
\]

\end{document}

The command \family is defined there so as to be usable in either of two ways:

A form such as \family{y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}, \dots} produces an angle-bracket delimited output consisting of what is given as the single argument.
A form such as \family{x_{i}; i; I}, using semicolons as separators in the single argument, produces the same output as would \langle x_{i}\rangle_{i \in I}.

The log shows this error:
./errQ.tex:17: Extra \else.
\MT_delim_formfamily_nostar_inner: ...ngle }\else 
                                                  \MT_etb_ifdefempty_x:nnn {...
l.17 y = \family{y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}, \dots}
                                            .

The same bug from amsmath infects, for example:
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\lis}[1]\lbrace\rbrace{#1}

as in:
Consider $\lis{0, 1, 2, \dots}$.

Added: known bug As comments indicated, the issue is a bug in the current version of amsmath: see Recently added bug to amsmath.

I haven't checked on your specific problem but I can say that loading amsmath is redundant since mathtools is an extension of amsmath. :-)

put a \relax after \dots. And wait for the update of amsmath tomorrow.

Alternatively use \ldots instead of \dots.

@SvendTveskæg true but it won't help here

@UlrikeFischer: is the \relax just a temporary measure until the next update to mathtools? In any case, can I modify the definitions of \family or \dofamily to avoid that?  (My "real" document is book-length with hundreds upon hundreds of instances of calls to \family !)

Exactly where and what is the problem with the definitions of the commands \family and \dofamily?

@DavidCarlisle I know; I just wanted to mention that loading both packages is redundant.

For the nonce, inserting \relax after #1 in \formfamily{#1} seems to fix things. Any harm in doing that?

no there is no harm, it's a bug in the latest amsmath version and we have reverted it to give more time for testing the intended change, sorry about the incovenience. the fixed code is already on ctan so should be in texlive/miktex mirrors before the end of the week at the latest

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1448

What version of amsmath do I want to avoid the bug until it is fixed? How do I get that version (I'm using TeXLive and the TeXLive Utility)?

as soon as you get the next update of amsmath, it will be fine. if it is already on ctan and you use TL, that will be very soon b/c TL picks up updates very quickly in general. (and I am certain they will not overlook this one.) I would strongly recommend using \relax until you get the fixed version from tlmgr. theoretically, you could get the updated version of amsmath yourself. or, if tlmgr saves backups, you could try rolling back. but I would not recommend doing either of those unless you know exactly what you are doing.

I didn't realize that the "extra \else" was due to the underlying definition of \dots. Otherwise, yes, same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/730161/13492.
